# statically linking multiple VC++ libraries to a C++/CLI dll

Tags: c#, linker, c++-cli

So I have this C# project that requires the use of some functions from a vc++ library.  This vc++ library is then dependent on other vc++ libraries.

So in order to get this working, I created a c++/cli dll project that wrapped the main vc++ library.  In the project linker settings, I just added the target vc++ library in the input field, and this resolved linker errors.  I then added a reference to the cli project to the c# project references.

Everything compiled fine, but when I ran the C# project, there was a File.IO.Exception saying that the cli dll couldn't be loaded.  After some tinkering around, I found that this error was happening because the wrapped vc++ dll dependencies could not be loaded.  So I copied the vc++ dll into the same folder as the c# exe.  I also had to copy all of the other vc++ dlls that the initial dll depended on.

Having to keep track of all of the VC++ dlls is burdensome, so I'm wondering if it is possible to statically link all of the VC++ dlls into the C++/CLI dll, so I do not have to copy them into the same folder as the C# exe.  I tried adding all of the vc++ dependencies to the linker input field but that didn't do anything.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: You cannot link DLLs into another DLL. Rebuilding them as static libraries would be a workaround.  Or just adding them to your project and setting their Copy to Output property to Copy if Newer.  Easy peasy.

Comment: So is it possible to link a static c++/cli library with a c# project?

Comment: No, C++/CLI doesn't support managed static libraries.  You can only link static libraries with native code.

Comment: Sorry, I think I meant linking the c# project to a static C++/CLI library.

Comment: No, C++/CLI doesn't support managed static libraries :)

Comment: Ok, well why is it that my vc++ dll project produces a dll and a lib file?  Are lib files supposed to be static libraries and dll files dynamic libraries?  If that's the case, shouldn't the lib file contain  all of the vc++ dependencies if it's statically linked?  Then there shouldn't be a reason to copy all of the vc++ dll's, since they're statically linked.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand why I need to provide the vc++ lib file in the c++/cli linker input field

Comment: so when you say rebuilding them as static libraries, i should be able to build a static version of the main vc++ library that needs to be wrapped, and all of its dependencies should be included, then link the c++/cli dll to it?